# Creating a new list that adds and sums elements from an old list

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list `xxs` and I need to create a new one that adds and sums elements from the old list.

Let me draw it to demonstrate:

[image: visualization of list transformation]

So, I have the list:

```
xxs = [("a","b", [(1,"a","b"),(2,"a","b")]), ("c","d",[(3,"a","b"),(4,"a","b")])]
```

My best approach so far is:

```
infoBasicas = [ (x,y,aux) | (x,y,_) <- xxs]
    where aux = sum [ z | (_,_,ys) <- xxs, (z,_,_) <- ys]
```

Output:

```
[("a","b",10),("c","d",10)]
```

Although I’m not far away… I'm not quite there yet and would really appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: So the type of `xxs` is `[(String, String, [(Integer, String, String)])]`? Why exactly do you have a value with such a horrendous type to begin with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem with you solution is that `aux` is the same for each element of `xxs`. when you write `(x,y,_) <- xxs`, you are throwing away the list with the numbers you want to sum. Instead, keep that list, working one element at a time, so:

```
infoBasicas = [(x, y, doSum innerList) | (x, y, innerList) <- xxs]
```

To find the sum of the `innerList`s, you only want the numbers, so you can throw them away. After that is done, you are left with a list of numbers, which can just be summed with the standard `sum` function:

```
doSum list = sum (fst3 list) -- There is one small error here. Can you see what it is?
fst3 (a, _, _) = a
```

Not that we are using `fst3` here, instead of `fst`, as these are triples, not pairs.

Comment: `doSum list = sum (Fst3 list)`  this line has an error.  But maybe that is just right for homework :-)

Answer (score 4):

You were really close!

As the gereeter said: your main problem is that you're using the same value of `aux` for everything. If you change `aux` into a function taking the list of `(Int,String,String)` tuples then it should work for you.

```
infoBasicas = [ (x,y,aux z) | (x,y,z) <- xxs ]
  where aux xs = sum [ z | (z,_,_) <- xs ]
```

(I haven't really added anything to gereeter's answer except to change the form of the sample code to more closely resemble yours.)